# Problems with asynchronous calls in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I had this idea for a new chrome extension:
It should create a linking QR code for the currently open website, displayed in the popup.html which can be easily scanned with the smartphone. If you watch a video on YouTube, the current time of the video should be also embedded in the QR code, which makes it possible to continue watching the video directly in the YouTube app on the smartphone.

So far so good. But now I have the following problem:
This extension works fine on all websites. Only on Youtube there seems to be a problem with the asynchrony of the onmessage listener and the sending of the message to the contentScript (requesting the current time of the viewed YouTube video).
In the debugging console I get the following errors:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

... getting this after trying to execute line 7 of background.js

> Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'videoTime' of undefined
>
> > at chrome-extension://...../background.js:8:70

... getting this after trying to execute line 8 of background.js

**popup.js**

```
$(function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({text: 'sendURL'}, function(response) {
        $('#qr-code').attr('src', getQRCodeImgURL(response.url));
    });
});

function getQRCodeImgURL(url) {
    var qrCodeURL = new URL('http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/');
    qrCodeURL.searchParams.set('data', encodeURI(url));
    qrCodeURL.searchParams.set('size', '200x200');
    return qrCodeURL;
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {

    if (message.text == 'sendURL') {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, /* lastFocusedWindow: true */}, function (tabs) {
            var currentURL = new URL(tabs[0].url);
            if (currentURL.href.indexOf('youtube.com/watch?v=') >= 0) { // if current website is youtube
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { text: 'sendVideoTime' }, function (response) {
                    const ytVideoTime = timeStringToSeconds(response.videoTime);

                    var ytURL = new URL('https://youtu.be/');
                    ytURL.pathname = '/' + currentURL.searchParams.get('v');
                    ytURL.searchParams.set('t', ytVideoTime);
                    currentURL = ytURL;
                    sendResponse({ url: currentURL.href });
                });
            } else {
                sendResponse({ url: currentURL.href });
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
});

function timeStringToSeconds(timeString) {
    var seconds = 0;
    var hms = timeString.split(':');
    if (hms.length == 3) {
        seconds = parseInt(hms[0])/* hours */ * 60 /* minutes per hour */ * 60 /* seconds per minute */;
        hms.shift(); /* remove first element, for accessing first element in next step (also if hms doesnt is in this hh:mm:ss format)  */
    }
    return seconds + (parseInt(hms[0]) * 60) /* seconds per minute */ + parseInt(hms[1]) /* seconds */;
}
```

**contentScript.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.text == 'sendVideoTime') {
        const time = document.evaluate('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[27]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.textContent;
        sendResponse({videoTime: time});
    }
    return true;
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "URL-QR-Code-Creator",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "This extension creates a linking QR code for the currently open website, which can be easily scanned with the smartphone. If you watch a video on the YouTube website, the current time of the video is also embedded in the QR code, which makes it possible to continue watching the video directly in the YouTube app on the smartphone.",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/qr-code-16px.png",
        "32": "images/qr-code-32px.png",
        "48": "images/qr-code-48px.png",
        "64": "images/qr-code-64px.png",
        "128": "images/qr-code-128px.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/qr-code-16px.png",
            "32": "images/qr-code-32px.png",
            "48": "images/qr-code-48px.png",
            "64": "images/qr-code-64px.png",
            "128": "images/qr-code-128px.png"
        },
        "default_title": "show QR-Code",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistant": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*"],
            "js": ["contentScript.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

Comment: "Receiving end does not exist" is telling you there was no content script running in the tab at the exact moment when the message was sent. Show us how you declare/inject contentScript.js

Comment: Added the manifest.json to my post above. :)

Comment: Youtube is a SPA site so when you open its homepage first and then navigate to the watch page, no content script will be running there. You need to match `"*://www.youtube.com/*"`

Comment: Changed the match pattern to "[star]://www.youtube.com/[star]" but still getting the same errors at the same time.

Comment: Well, you need to reload both the extension and the tab. Also, if youtube is still loading, your content script won't run yet so you may want to specify [run_at](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time).

Comment: I know that I have to update both.
So it can't be because of that, I think.
The funny thing is that after I restarted the browser, the first attempt to load the qr code on a YouTube video worked. On the second attempt, however, the above errors occurred again, even after a reload.
I now have added the line for the content_scripts:
"run_at": "document_idle"
, reloaded extension and tab and restarted the browser - also without any success.
Thanks for trying to help me @wOxxOm

Comment: You should try `document_start`, not `idle`.

Comment: Also with `document_start` still not working.

Comment: "Not working" means you see the same error text? Are you looking at the error list in chrome://extensions page? That list shows old entries so you need to click a button in the top right corner to clear it.

Comment: Not working means that the QR code is not generated and the popup window remains empty. The messages can be seen both in the console of the extension (which is automatically emptied when reloading the extension) and on the chrome://extensions page (I know that this remains when reloading).

Comment: Verify that the content script runs at all on youtube either by adding a console.log inside or by opening `Content Scripts` panel in devtools. Maybe it's a bug in Chrome or you have something in `chrome://policy` that blocks youtube.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

At first I said goodbye to the idea of regulating access to the youtube DOM via an extra content script.
So I deleted contentScript.js and deleted it from manifest.json.
Now I simply accessed the DOM using the [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) method in the background.js file and got the result using the callback function. Quite simply - without having to send messages around all the time.